# Should an IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> really be an IObservable<T>?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

Consider a method `DoSomething()` which returns:

1. `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> DoSomething()`
2. `IObservable<T> DoSomething()`

Considering both:

- Should the method FlatMap the IEnumerable into an IObservable?
- Should it be left to the consumer to do as they please?
- Is one way or the other more *correct*?
- Does it matter either way, your consumer should really do as they please, the intent is the same in either being returned?

Comment: To me it is conceptually different for a method to return `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>` than for it to return `IObservable<T>`. In the first case, the method says that it is an _observable_ sequence of an _enumerable_ sequence of _T_'s that I'll return. Whereas, in the second case it says that I will return an _observable_ sequence of _T_'s.

Comment: Indeed.  It depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>` does differ semantically from `IObservable<T>`.

`IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>` represents zero or more moments in time where zero or more values are reported.

`IObservable<T>` represents zero or more moments in time where a single value is reported.

The former can then be used to represent the activity between points in time and returning an empty enumerable would positively represent nil activity since the last value. The latter cannot explicitly do that.

These two forms can therefore be used to represent two different real-world ways or reporting values.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the signature of this [`Observable.Buffer` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212130(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
IObservable<IList<TSource>> Buffer<TSource>(IObservable<TSource> source, int count)
```

Clearly it wouldn't be very useful if the result was flattened to an `IObservable<TSource>`.

As you said yourself, `IObservable<T>` and `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>` are conceptually different.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with returning `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>` if that's what your method means. Buffer is one example where it makes sense - anything with batching would make sense. If you had a service that accepted batched requests for orders, then an `IObservable<IEnumerable<Order>>` could be valid. You could flatten it, and that might also be valid.

It depends whether the concept of the batch/buffer itself is integral to what your method is supposed to do. If your method just happens to be using buffer to achieve its aims, but the method isn't a batch operation by nature, then it will probably be more intuitive to flatten the Observable.

Comment: True, IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> is appropriate for batching methods where it makes sense. But in other cases, the correctness of saying I return an observable sequence of enumerable Ts in the future is what I was trying to answer

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise the types weren't displaying properly. I think we're on the same page - another wording of my answer is: unless the client/caller of the method specifically wants a stream of buffers, groups or chunks, return a flattened Observable. This would be especially important for loosely typed languages like javascript.